# Get closest cell with a value before the current

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In a column filled mostly by blank cells, I need to get the value of the cell thats closest to the currently selected one, in a row before it, and isn't blank.

While the "isn't blank" part can be easily achieved with the an **IF** and **ISBLANK** statement, I can't figure out how to get the position of the first cell upwards from the current one that isn't blank.

[image: Excel Sheet]

In this example spreadsheet, in the cell C7 I want to display the value of B7 minus the value of B4 (**=B7-B4**). The problem is that these values are **separated by an unpredictable number of cells**, which can range from 0 to 20 or even more. Needing to parse a spreadsheet with thousands of rows and frequent data added, selecting the upper cell manually is not an option.

In continuation of my example, I want C13 to display **=B13-B10**, but lets say there were two more blank rows in between them (row 13 becomes row 15), I would want it to display =B15-**B10**.

Can the position be obtained with a **MATCH** query, knowing that the Types will always be T1 or T2?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter this formula in cell `C2` and drag it to the bottom.

`=IFERROR(IF(B2="","",B2-LOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,B$1:B1)),"")`

[image]

Comment: Trying it in a Google Drive Spreadsheet because the Excel I have installed has a different language package, I get a "Formula Analysis Error" in every cell I try to input your formula.

Comment: Then address your question accordingly, you asked for Excel formula and received a valid answer.

Comment: I don't know if you realise what I'm saying - I pasted your formula (that apparently works in your screenshot somehow) in a spreadsheet just as the one described, and I get an error.

Comment: Thought you meant you get this error in google sheets. Appologize, try finding correct formula names for your Excel language version.

Comment: Solved my problem after installing the English language package, converting commas to semicolons and the dot in 9.99999999999999E+307 to a comma. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Writing formulae via VBA**

Below you find a VBA approach writing your subtracting formulae to column C.
*BTW, searching via array is much more quicker than looping through a range.*

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub subtractLastValueRow()
' declare vars
  Dim oSht    As Worksheet                       ' work sheet
  Dim a       As Variant                         ' one based 2-dim data field array
  Dim n       As Long                            ' last row in column B
  Dim i       As Long                            ' item no
  Dim ii      As Long                            ' last item no
  Dim j       As Long
  Dim s       As String
' set sheet
  Set oSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")  ' fully qualified reference to worksheet
' get last row number of search column
  n = oSht.Range("B" & oSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  If n < 2 Then Exit Sub                         ' only if data avaible (row 1 = title line)

' get range (after title line) values to one based 2dim data field array
  a = oSht.Range("B2:C" & n).Value               '  array gets data from e.g. "A2:A100"
' loop through column B to find keyword sKey
  If Len(a(1, 1) & "") > 0 Then ii = 1 + 1       '  first item in array
  For i = LBound(a) + 1 To UBound(a)             '  array boundaries counting from 1+1 to n -1 (one off for title line)
      ' value found
        If Len(a(i, 1) & "") > 0 Then
           For j = i + 1 To UBound(a)
               If Len(a(j, 1) & "") > 0 Then
                ' write .Formula (alternatively use .Value, if value wanted)
                  oSht.Range("C" & i + 1).Formula = "=B" & i + 1 & "-B" & ii
                  ii = i + 1                      '  note last found i
                  Exit For
                End If
           Next j
        End If
  Next
  If Len(a(UBound(a), 1) & "") > 0 Then           ' last item in array
     oSht.Range("C" & UBound(a) + 1).Formula = "=B" & UBound(a) + 1 & "-B" & ii
  End If
End Sub
```

**Note**

If you want to write values instead of *work sheet formulae*, simply replace `.Formula` with `.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

In cell C3 put following formula:

`=B3-LOOKUP(2,1/$B$1:B2,$B$1:B2)`

And copy down in all T2 cells as required.

Comment: Your formula should be preceded by an `If` condition: `If(Left(A3,1)="T",B3-LOOKUP(2,1/$B$1:B2,$B$1:B2),"") to solve OP.

Comment: Trying it in a Google Drive Spreadsheet because the Excel I have installed has a different language package, I get a "Formula Analysis Error" in every cell I try to input your formula.